# How fsi image is stored in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

How fsi image is stored in hadoop(secondary namenode fsimage format), like table format or file format. If file format means it is compressed or non compressed and it is readable format?

Thanks
venkatbala

Answer (score 0):

Fsimage is an “Image” file and It is not in a human-readable format. You have to use HDFS Offline Image Viewer in Hadoop to convert it to a readable format.

Answer (score 0):

The contents of the fsimage is just an "Image" and cannot be read with  "CAT". Basically the fsimage content has the meta data information like directory structure ,transaction ,etc . There is a tool "oiv "  using it you can convert the fsimage into text file .

Download the fsimage using

```
 hdfs dfsadmin -fetchImage /tmp
```

Then excute the below command -i - input , -o output

```
 hdfs oiv -i fsimage_0000000000000001382 -o /tmp/fsimage.txt
```

Comment: Offline Image Viewer (oiv)